# Ionic Framework and SVN

Tags: svn, ionic-framework

I would like to use Subversion with my Ionic project. What are files to be ignored in the Subversion?

Comment: Hi Florent, I see you're new to StackOverflow. Did my answer provide help to you? If so, consider it marking as a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the one I use with Git for Ionic (my `.gitignore` file):

```
# Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore when using Git
# http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

node_modules/
platforms/
plugins/
```

Basically the same would apply for SVN.

Comment: can you explore more? how to incorporate svn with ionic project?

Comment: What problem are you getting into? With what exactly would you need additional help?

Comment: See,  Either GIT or SVN/Source Control I have to connect with my company server. So That more than one developer can work on single project simultaneously .

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. The whole point of any control version system *is* that more developers can work on a single project simultaneously. That's something that you get out of the box with them - nothing additional has to be set for that. I understand that you have some setup that makes it difficult to do so, as you have to connect to your company server? If so, I would talk with your system admin and explain to him what you're trying to achieve.